# Name of a training field for dogs

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for a training field for dogs? Where owners bring their canines to tame / train them together with other owners.

Comment: We call these *[dog parks](https://theokdogblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/mills-river-dog-park/)*

Comment: @PhilSweet even if this "park" has "obstacles" for dogs to run through / across / over?

Comment: @PhilSweet your commercial does not mention the word "train" or "training".

Answer (score 1):

One word used is **arena**.

I cannot find this *specific* usage in a dictionary to refer to, but there are plenty of commercial websites which say a **dog training arena** is available. Because they are commercial, I don't link them but they are easy to find from the phrase.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for a word, specifically dedicated to it, but probably it does not exist. +1